# How to remove machineName from Url

Tags: iis

Hello I have server on which I keep my intranet app.
At this moment app is under adress : [MachineName].[Domain].com

Can anyone tell me how to change it to something like:

[newName].[Domain].com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an alias (CNAME) in your DNS to register `newName` as an alias for `MachineName`.